# jQuery select one HTML element generated by Rails loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner with Rails and jQuery. I have a view in a Rails app which contains pictures for each User in the database. The user photos are generated with a .each loop, and an  HTML element. And what I want jQuery to do is this: when I mouseover one of the  HTML elements, I want it to expand to include some content. But I only want ITS content to expand, not all of the other contents with the same class name! How can I do this?

Here's the view:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li class="span2-thumb">
    <a href=<%= user_path(user) %> class="thumbnail">
      <img src=<%= user.photo_url(:thumb).to_s %>>
    </a>
  </li>

    <li class="span2-info hidden">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src=<%= user.photo_url(:thumb).to_s %>>
        <p>
           Content...
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
$('.span2-thumb').on({
    mouseenter: function(evt) {
        $('.span2-thumb').addClass('hidden');
        $('.span2-info').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
$('.span2-info').on({
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.span2-info').addClass('hidden');
        $('.span2-thumb').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

One option would be to create custom class names for each user image. I can do this without issue, by appending the user.id to the class name. But then I have the problem that I can't write a script to identify each unique class name!

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go. This should work:

Sorry, the first answer was stupid. I think you ought to nest the two toggled elements.

Edit your markup to this:

```
<li class="span2-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="thumb">
      <img src="path/to/img">
    </a>
    <div class="thumbnail hidden">
      <img src="path/to/img">
      <p>
         Content...
      </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Use this for your js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.span2-thumb').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).children().toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this just seems to delete each element when I mouse over it. Not sure that it is seeing the .closest element

Answer (score 0):

**Pure css version** -- I try to avoid excessive JS when possible

```
.span2-thumb:hover .thumb {
  display: none;
}
.span2-thumb:hover .thumbnail {
  display: block;
}
.span2-thumb .thumbnail {
  display: none;
}
```